# what are parts: and path: in sapui5 and why are they used?

Tags: sapui5

What is the use of `parts` and `path` in SAPUI5 while dealing with models?

Can someone explain me with respect to the following code (where `invoice` is a JSONModel)?

```xml
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.InvoiceList"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <List
            headerText="{i18n>invoiceListTitle}"
        class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
        width="auto"
        items="{invoice>/Invoices}">
        <items>
            <ObjectListItem
                title="{invoice>Quantity} x {invoice>ProductName}"
                number="{
                    parts: [{path: 'invoice>ExtendedPrice'}, {path: 'view>/currency'}],
                    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                    formatOptions: {
                        showMeasure: false
                    }
                }"
                numberUnit="{view>/currency}"
                numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 50 ? 'Error' : 'Success' }">
                <firstStatus>
                    <ObjectStatus text="{
                        path: 'invoice>Status',
                        formatter: '.formatter.statusText'
                    }"/>
                </firstStatus>
            </ObjectListItem>

        </items>
    </List>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

What you are referencing is called *binding*. In your example, you have:

- List binding: `items="{invoice>/Invoices}"`.
- Simple property binding: `numberUnit="{view>/currency}"`.
- Composite property binding: `number="{parts: [...]}` (with explicit syntax) and `title="{invoice>Quantity} x {invoice>ProductName}"` (with complex syntax).
- Expression binding: `numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 50 ? 'Error' : 'Success' }"`

The SDK has a few extensive documentation pages about these topics, under the chapter [Data binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247).

**List binding** is used to create a collection of controls, based on the data inside the model (either based on a list or a map of objects). Conceptually, you can imagine that UI5 loops through your values and instantiates the corresponding control using a template or a factory function. The *path* in this case is the (relative or absolute) path towards the collection.

**Simple property binding** is used just to fill in a property of a control from your model based on a single scalar field in the model. The *path* here is the (relative or absolute) path towards the property.

**Composite property binding** can be used to fill a property of a control based on multiple fields, which are combined through either a formatter function or a type (like the currency in your example). For example, when using a formatter, each `part` will be passed as a parameter to your function (e.g. if you have 2 parts, your formatter should expect 2 parameters). The *parts* here are used to define each individual field that you want to use when computing the property value.

Expression binding or the complex syntax is simply a form of syntactic sugar to allow you to define a formatter inline without having to write a dedicate JS function.

You always can use the simplified syntax `property="{/path}"` or the extended syntax `property="{path: '/path'}"`, which are equivalent (but you are forced to use the extended syntax once you want to specify more binding parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would also like to know what is the use of showMeasure : false here in this example

Comment: The `showMeasure` property is part of the currency format options (check [the documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat/methods/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance) for a full list of properties), which toggles the display of the currency symbol on and off.

Comment: It is most likely set to `false` due to the fact that you already show the currency inside the separate `numberUnit` property of the list item. If it were true, then you would have e.g. the EUR symbol twice: one in the `numberUnit` and once inside the `number` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking, within **path** you can only bind with exactly one property or value, and **parts** can let you bind multiple properties or values which sometimes is very useful.

In you example, the Currency formatting requires two parameters, one is amount, the other is currency, you have to use parts to parse two parameters.

Also when you write your own formatter function, if you would like more parameters, you can also use parts to receive these parameters.

This is called **Composite Binding**.

Regards,
Marvin